# Ansible - convert simple list to a simple dict

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I have the following list:

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
    
      vars:
        list1: [1,2,3,4]  

      tasks:
```

I need this to be of a type dict with key-value pairs where each member of list (1,2,3,4,...n) will have key "a".

```
dict1: [{a: 1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}]
```

I know there is list2dict filter, but couldn't find examples or literature that would explain it how to do it. PS there can be n number of items in the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See filter [community.general.dict_kv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries). For example,

```yaml
dict1: "{{ list1|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'a') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
dict1:
  - a: 1
  - a: 2
  - a: 3
  - a: 4
```